# Introduction to geometric discrepancy theory?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, st.statistics, textbook-recommendation

Recently in search of tests for uniformity of multidimensional  distributions I luckily stumbled upon something called 'geometric discrepancy theory'. It seems to be a very powerful and elegant subject which interconnects algebraic geometry, number theory, statistics, stochastic integration and computational complexity. It sounds a lot like something I'd like to study, however there are some questions:

**What prerequisites should I have?**

How well should I know core algebraic geometry? My knowledge are limited by [Cox](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3319167200), which, I suspect, is not enough. Moreover, what over advanced topics will be useful to know beforehand?

**What are recommended texts?**

By now I found this interesting book ["Applied Algebra and Number Theory"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N4PM3N0) by collective of authors, however it's unclear if it suited for first reading on subject. If you studied this subjects before, what sources do you consider particularly useful.  Personally, I prefer books with geometric presentation and multitude of problems and exercises to work through.

I'm grateful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should certainly read Matousek's book "Geometric Discrepancy - An Illustrated Guide", which is very accessible. Another good introduction is Chazelle's "The Discrepancy Method: Randomness and Complexity".